# Guzzle always convert all my headers to lowercase

Tags: php, curl, guzzle, php-curl

I have a script that uses guzzle to make an API call. The api server checks for headers and it is case sensitive.

Below is an example code of mine

```
<?php

$headers = [
    'set_headers' => [
        'Connection'             => 'Keep-Alive',
        'Accept-Encoding'        => ‘gzip’,
        'Accept-Language'        => ‘en_US’,
        'US-Token'               => '1f23a-d234s-3s45d-452g',
        'AToken'                 => 'XXXX'
    ],
];

// Build HTTP request object.
$request = \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request( // Throws (they didn't document that properly).
    'POST',
    'htps://api.website.com/',
    $headers,
    bodystream() //StreamInterface
);

// Default request options (immutable after client creation).
$_guzzleClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'handler'         => $stack, // Our middleware is now injected.
    'allow_redirects' => [
        'max' => 8, // Allow up to eight redirects (that's plenty).
    ],
    'connect_timeout' => 30.0, // Give up trying to connect after 30s.
    'decode_content'  => true, // Decode gzip/deflate/etc HTTP responses.
    'timeout'         => 240.0, // Maximum per-request time (seconds).
    // Tells Guzzle to stop throwing exceptions on non-"2xx" HTTP codes,
    // thus ensuring that it only triggers exceptions on socket errors!
    // We'll instead MANUALLY be throwing on certain other HTTP codes.
    'http_errors'     => false,
]);


// Add critically important options for authenticating the request.
$guzzleOptions = [
    'cookies' => ($_cookieJar instanceof CookieJar ? $_cookieJar : false),
    'verify'  => file_exists('/etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem') ? '/etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem' : $_verifySSL,
    'proxy'   => ($_proxy !== null ? $_proxy : null),
    'curl'    => [
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2, // Make http client work with HTTP 2/0
        CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => 1,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
    ]
];

// Attempt the request. Will throw in case of socket errors!
$response = $_guzzleClient->send($request, $guzzleOptions); ?>
```

I tested the same request with cURL and it works perfectly. Is there a way I can rectify this in the guzzle php library, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you [edit] to include a small self-contained example of how your creating the request in Guzzle?

Comment: Actually, guzzle implementation follows PSR-7, which states "Despite that headers may be retrieved case-insensitively, the original case MUST be preserved by the implementation, in particular when retrieved with `getHeaders()`.", so minimal example would be great.

Comment: @IMSoP I’ve added an example code to my question

Comment: @Anton I just added an example code to my question above

Comment: Ah! I might be wrong, but using HTTP/2 may be your issue here. It transmits the HTTP headers in a special binary format called [HPACK](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7541), and the encoder (probably [nghttp2](https://nghttp2.org/)) may be what's lower-casing the headers as part of that.

Comment: Since it might give extra clues, can you include a) where you've seen the lower-case headers (is it all of them, or just some that are lower-cased?); and b) the cURL command you've used which worked correctly.